# Help with さすが大学に行っただけのことはある

Tags: grammar, translation, usage

It's an example sentence from tangorin.com, I wanted to know some sentence examples for さすが. One sentence I found is completely confusing for me, I can't logically translate the sentence to the original translation below:

> 彼は**さすが**大学に**行っただけのことはある**。
>   He didn't go to college for nothing.

The really confusing part is especially the rear 行っただけのことはある. 
I know that simply said ことがある means 'to have done something', concluding that (in my mind) the translation would be something like:

> This guy, as one would expect, he *did* really go to university [*only* for the
>   sake of going to the university].

Giving you the image that this guy is some bum instead of the right translation which gives you the image that this guy is actually something.

But, as you can see, my translation is nowhere near the original (right) translation, also due to my level of Japanese being only somewhere around B2.

Comment: I kind of see the drill. Would following phrase then be correct?

デスヴァレーを呼ぶだけのことはある。

If I wanted to say "There's a reason they call it Death Valley / They don't call it Death Valley for nothing!".

Comment: Almost perfect. It's デスヴァレー**と**呼ぶだけのことはある, using quotative particle `と`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%95%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C

> さすがは～だけあって
>   （just） as expected of
>   （just） as you'd expect of
>   just as one would expect from
>   just like

From my understanding, It's basically saying "**It was no surprise that he went to a University**". The sentence puts emphasis on it not being much of a surprise, that the person speaking didn't expect anything less the man in the sentence.

In this example the だけのことはある should put even more emphasis on the fact that it's little surprise that he went to a University. Probably means that the person is quite smart.

another example of だけのことはある

http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B

> さすが～と呼ばれるだけのことはある
>   not known as ~ for nothing